# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/BasicAWSCredentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3

This code

```
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials
            = new BasicAWSCredentials(WasabiCredential.ACCESS_KEY, WasabiCredential.SECRET_KEY);
    final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("s3.wasabisys.com", "us-east-1"))
            .build();
```

Throws:

*Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/BasicAWSCredentials*

Given:

- I already added maven-shade-plugin still this problem exists.
- The packaged jar contains `BasicAWSCredentials.class` under `\com\amazonaws\auth` folder

Comment: Try checking your .m2 folder for the appropriate AWS jar. You may have to delete the jar and then do a maven update. I usually get this error when the jar is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It turned out I had a scope incorrect, it was:

```
        <scope>test</scope>
```

So of course it was failing anywhere except during tests. I removed it and it did help.